# What does this rails condition do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have this piece of code:

```
  def get_auth_token
    if auth_token = params[:auth_token].blank? && request.headers["auth_token"]
      params[:auth_token] = auth_token
    end
  end
```

Can someone explain the if statement and what happens here? I'm not too fluent in ROR so I'm having a hard time figuring this syntax out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer is incorrect. Your code can be roughly translated into this:

```
if params[:auth_token].blank?
  params[:auth_token] = request.headers["auth_token"]
end
```

That is, if "auth_token" in params is blank it is set to "auth_token" from headers.
It isn't set only to `true` because boolean operators do not return singleton booleans in Ruby:

```
true && "abcde" #=> "abcde"
nil || 42 #=> 42
nil && nil #=> nil
```

I only omitted one conditional from your code, here goes the complete translation:

```
if params[:auth_token].blank? and request.headers["auth_token"]
  params[:auth_token] = request.headers["auth_token"]
end
```

The only difference is when `params[:auth_token] = ""` and `request.headers["auth_token"] = nil` the parameter won't change to nil. Which is a very minor thing I'm not sure if you care about this.

If there weren't any blank strings involved, you could express it more clear with Ruby's "or equal" operator:

```
params[:auth_token] ||= request.headers["auth_token"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **description**:

```
  def get_auth_token
    if auth_token = params[:auth_token].blank? && request.headers["auth_token"]
    # sets the var auth_token to true/false inside the IF statement to
    # true IF params[:auth_token] is empty or nil AND 
    # request.headers["auth_token"] is not nil (but could be empty)
      params[:auth_token] = auth_token
      # set the params[:auth_token] to auth_token (which could only be true)
    end
  end
```

That means, in **human language**:

> If the request sent an empty `params[:auth_token]` (or none) **AND** the
>   HTTP request contains in its headers a value (could be empty) for the key `"auth_token"`,
>   it will set the `params[:auth_token]` to `true`;

The **longer version**:

```
def get_auth_token
  auth_token = ( params[:auth_token].blank? && request.headers["auth_token"] ) # can be true/false
  if auth_token
    params[:auth_token] = auth_token
  end
end
```

The **shorter version** (you could refactor your code to this):

```
def get_auth_token
    params[:auth_token] = true if params[:auth_token].blank? && request.headers["auth_token"].present?
end
```

Comment: What is `rams` ? Did you mean `params` ?